# Need To Blink Text in GridView using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to blink some text in GridView Using Jquery its working outside GridView but i implemented the same inside the GridView its not working can any 1 please point me to my issue here is the link of my sample application if any 1 want to see the source code : [Link to my Sample Application](http://www.mediafire.com/file/oxk90bjsmfqa03f/Grid.rar)

Here is some part of my code

***Javascript Function***

[image]

***ASPX Code***

[image]

***CodeBehind Code***

[image]

the Above code is working for the div which is outside the GridView but not working for the div which is inside the GridView... Please point me where i am going wrong...

Thanks

Comment: @Adrian it's all about UI and what users are used to ... see the police cars? they have blinking lights ;o)

Comment: Not the cause of the problem, but you you don't need to use $(selector) inside the function.  It's redundant since you are already passing in a jquery object.  Simply selector.fadeOut() would work opposed to $(selector).fadeOut()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  I would set a class on the mycontent div and remove the runat="server".

Then just use css to make the text blink.  text-decoration: blink;  Also, remove those font and strong tags and use css instead...

Or:

Use the blink plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blink

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ClassAddedToMyContent").blink();
});

<div class="ClassAddedToMyContent">
    <asp:literal id="literal" runat="server" /> <!-- Literals won't wrap in spans -->
</div>
```

Comment: `text-decoration: blink` has no effect under IE.

Answer (score 1):

because an `<asp:label>` results in a `<span>`, and you will have 2 `<span>`'s.

show us the `BlinkByText` method so we can help you change it to incorporate one more `<span>`